# Why is an electric and magnetic field present in all universe?

Tags: electromagnetism, cosmology, magnetic-fields, universe, electric-fields

Planet Earth has its fields due to the motion of molten metals in the core but how does this whole universe has its fields without any discontinuity? And, can we say for sure that fields are present in the whole universe as we can see light traveling thousands of light year,  but as light is an EM wave it can't travel without the presence of fields.

Comment: What do you mean by discontinuity? Discontinuity has a specific mathematical meaning, but I think you are just asking about the vanishing of E and B fields. Also, if you tell us why you *think* there are E/M fields in the whole universe, we can answer better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't E and B fields in the entire universe. For example, there are no electric fields inside a conductor. I'm sure there are quite a few other such examples.

If you mean "why are there electromagnetic waves throughout the entire universe?", one answer is because the radiation field drops like $1/r$, so the field from a single source never "vanishes".

Notice there might be something wrong with your assumptions - in order to prove there is E/M radiation throughout the entire universe, we would have to observe the entire universe. Since we can't (our observable universe is finite in size), your assumption is not experimentally verifiable. That's one reason I asked for the clarification in my comment.

EDIT: On a sidenote, you might want to check out Olber's Paradox (http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/GR/olbers.html)

Comment: this question came to my mind after reading on NASA website that a gamma explosion took place nearly 12.8 billion light year away. which means that their are fields present in almost all know universe. otherwise light couldn't have traveled till here.

Comment: Right, in that case you are talking about how quickly the fields drop off as a function of distance. The fields go as $1/r$, but the intensity of the light drops off as $1/r^2$ (this is called the inverse square law). Therefore, they never go to zero except when $r=\infty$. This does not take into account redshifting or the expansion of the universe, but that's why you can always see unobstructed objects in the visible universe.